# Have I allocated memory correctly in 2d vector?

Tags: c++, vector, declaration, outofrangeexception

I tried to do a calendar with regular affairs(like payment) and get `out_of_range` when added an affair to 31 January.
So I think that I allocated a memory incorrectly in my 2d vector. Also, I tried debugging, but I couldn't check the size of the vector(month) from the vector of vectors. So I also tried a `sizeof` but he shows 0
in this case: `cout << sizeof(business) / sizeof(business[0][0]);` and 1 in this: `cout << sizeof(business) / sizeof(business[0]);`.
Input is:
 `12 Add 5 Salary
Add 31 Walk`

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

void Add(vector<vector<string>>& business, const int current_month)
{
    int current_day;
    string s;
    cout << "Enter a day, please" << endl;
    cin >> current_day;
    cout << "Enter your business, please" << endl;
    cin >> s;
    current_day -= 1;
    business[current_month][current_day] = s;
}

int main()
{
    int current_month = 0;
    vector<int> count_of_days_in_months =  { 31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31 };
    vector<vector<string> > business(12, vector<string>(( count_of_days_in_months[current_month] ) - 1));
    cout << sizeof(business) / sizeof(business[0][0]);
    int Q;
    cin >> Q;
    string command;
    for (int j = 0; j < Q; j++)
    {
        cout << "Enter a command, please" << endl;
        cin >> command;
        if (command == "Add")
            Add(business, current_month);
        else if (command == "Dump")
            Dump(business, current_month);
        else if (command == "Next")
            Next(business, count_of_days_in_months, current_month);
    }

}
```

Comment: The size of a vector is obtained by calling `.size()` on it. `sizeof(business) / sizeof(business[0][0])` is wrong. Where exactly does the exception occur? Nothing you are showing can throw that exception. Please provide a [repro].

Comment: If you want to know how many elements are in a `std::vector`, use `.size()`, such as `business.size()`.

Comment: Correction: The only thing in the shown code that can throw `std::out_of_range` is `cin >> current_day;`. Please show a complete [repro] including the input you used.

Comment: @walnut there is a full code.
https://pastebin.com/aG61NZ6Q
function main and Add.

Comment: @Leeker Please add code directly to your question and reduce it to the minimum necessary to reproduce the problem.

Comment: @walnut input is 

12
Add 5 Salary
Add 31 Walk

( Q is the amount of operations)
Ok, one moment

Comment: @Leeker Make it a double on "reduce it to the minimum necessary to reproduce the problem"

Comment: @walnut
fixed it. Now it has to be a minimal reproducible code.

Comment: `31` is out-of-bounds, because you will index `business[0][30]` with it, but the length of `business[0]` is only `30`. I don't know why you are subtracting `1` when you construct the vector...

Comment: @Leeker Yes, because your vector is one too short to access index `30`, i.e. day `31`. Just remove `- 1` from `vector<vector<string> > business(12, vector<string>(( count_of_days_in_months[current_month] ) - 1));`. But even then you probably want each of the inner vectors to have different length not the same...

Comment: @walnut because of indexation starts from 0. After a user input a 31, I subtract 1 for entered value.

Comment: @Leeker Yes, but the `vector` constructor takes the *number of elements*, not the *index of the last element* as argument.

Comment: @walnut for different vectors I used reserve( Also, I think I can use resize)

Comment: @walnut Ooh, I got it, thanks, I forget about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `std::vector` constructors are endlessly confusing to memorize. This constructor is getting called:

```cpp
std::vector::vector(size_type n, const value_type& v)
```

which create n items and copies v to each one. The result is an array of 12 items, each with the same number of days as the current month.

It looks like you want to allocate a whole year's worth of days using that table. I don't know a constructor for `std::vector` that does that. But it's not a lot of code to do it manually:

```cpp
std::vector<std::vector<string>> business;
business.reserve(count_of_days_in_months.size());
for (auto days : count_of_days_in_months) {
    business.emplace_back(days); 
}
```

Demo: https://godbolt.org/z/Jd_94W